# How to find the coefficent of a term in a Dirichlet generating function in Mathematica?

Tags: mathematica, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-convolution

For a normal Dirichlet generating function like $Zeta[s]^2$, I can get the coefficient of the n-th term by applying Dirichlet convolution of the two constant functions. But how to find the coefficient of the n-th term of a Dirichlet generating functions like $1/(2-Zeta[s])$ or $Zeta[s-1]$? It seems there is no function in Mathematica to find the coefficient directly(c.f. to get the coefficient of a formal power series by using *SeriesCoefficient[...]*). Please be advised, thanks!

Comment: This is better asked in [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) but I don't think that there is a direct way to do this in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(s)=\sum_na_nn^{-s}$ be some Dirichlet series that converges absolutely at $\Re(s)=\sigma$. Then we have

$$
\lim_{T\to\infty}{1\over2iT}\int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}F(s)x^s\mathrm ds=
\begin{cases}
a_n & x=n \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Perhaps plugging this integral into Mathematica would work.

Comment: This integration looks formidable. I will try it. thanks!

Comment: Yes, straight from IANT from T. Apostol. But... how is this integral plugged into Mathematica? To me this seems not that easy at all. What do you think? ( Looks like a Mellin Transformation, or am I mistaking? )

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to manually calculate one term's coefficient by substituting the term $(Zeta[s] - 1)$ to the original series and then expand it into a Maclaurin formal power series . For a given n, the coefficient can be found by ordered factorization enumeration.

Comment: Sounds very interesting! Are you willing to elaborate on this? With an example perhaps?